# Unauthorised error from getProfile when using node-auth0

Tags: node.js, auth0

I am trying to migrate authentication via auth0 from a jvm based solution which uses auth0 rest api to a node based solution using node-auth0.
At present its a 2 step process:

1. Get token via `POST /oauth/token`
2. Get user profile via `/userInfo`

In the node application, I am constructing `AuthenticationClient` while providing `clientId`, `clientSecret` and `domain` as `AuthenticationClientOptions` and able to get the token successfully using `passwordGrant` but when I use the same `authenticationClient` object to call `getProfile` while providing the token obtained from passwordGrant, I get this error:

```
Request failed with status code 401
```

What’s confusing is that in Auth0 dashboard, this request is successful.

I am using `node-auth0 SDK Version: 2.42.0` on `Node 15.14.0`

Answer (score 0):

The token obtained via passwordGrant will be processed to respond for userInfo. Hence, the token must have in its audience claim `<your-auth0-domain>/userInfo`.